# NTFS $MFTMirr does not match $MFT

Tags: mount, ntfs

I was copying files in `Linux Mint` to `NTFS` external `USB` disk when I moved my laptop, probably USB connection was lost and now I got error `$MFTMirr does not match $MFT`. Mount error message is to use Windows to fix drive errors. However, I want to use Linux to fix that IMHO common error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ran `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1` (where sdb1 is the device name from error message) and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

2019 UPDATE: 
On some recent Linux releases, you need to install ntfs-3g utilties:

Open TERMINAL and write:

sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g

(Or download from http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/)

And after write:

sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1 (where sdb1 is the device name from error message)

THIS WILL RECOVER THE CORRUPTED MTF TO NORMAL and
RECOVER YOUR CONTROL ON YOUR EXTERNAL DRIVE (in LINUX OS environtment).